# Firebase/Crashlytics events detected and uploaded but not visible

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have an Android application with Crashlytics setup as per the latest instructions on https://firebase.google.com/. Also the versions are the latest. I have some issues in the sense that not all crashes are visible in the console. I would say only a few of them are, even if the crashes are detected and uploaded correctly. In the Logcat I see the message "report upload complete". This is an example trace of when I try to force a crash:

```
2020-05-03 08:48:30.840 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics Core 2.7.0.33
2020-05-03 08:48:30.865 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Exception handling initialization successful
2020-05-03 08:48:30.866 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog I/CrashlyticsInitProvider: CrashlyticsInitProvider initialization successful
2020-05-03 08:48:30.873 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Opening a new session with ID 5EAE693E0364-0001-1950-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:33.762 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Initialization marker file created.
2020-05-03 08:48:33.766 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Found invalid session part file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE691400E6-0001-1476-E9711228CB99SessionEvent0000000000.cls_temp
2020-05-03 08:48:33.766 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Found invalid session part file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE69240359-0001-15F1-E9711228CB99SessionEvent0000000000.cls_temp
2020-05-03 08:48:33.766 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Found invalid session part file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99SessionEvent0000000000.cls_temp
2020-05-03 08:48:33.767 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Found invalid session part file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE692E03B0-0001-174B-E9711228CB99SessionEvent0000000000.cls_temp
2020-05-03 08:48:33.767 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Found invalid session part file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionEvent0000000000.cls_temp
2020-05-03 08:48:33.767 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Found invalid session part file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE693803E1-0001-1863-E9711228CB99SessionEvent0000000000.cls_temp
2020-05-03 08:48:33.769 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE691400E6-0001-1476-E9711228CB99BeginSession.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.770 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE691400E6-0001-1476-E9711228CB99BeginSession.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.770 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE691400E6-0001-1476-E9711228CB99SessionApp.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.770 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE691400E6-0001-1476-E9711228CB99SessionApp.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.771 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE691400E6-0001-1476-E9711228CB99SessionOS.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.771 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE691400E6-0001-1476-E9711228CB99SessionOS.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.771 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE691400E6-0001-1476-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.771 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE691400E6-0001-1476-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.772 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE691400E6-0001-1476-E9711228CB99SessionEvent0000000000.cls_temp
2020-05-03 08:48:33.772 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE69240359-0001-15F1-E9711228CB99BeginSession.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.772 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE69240359-0001-15F1-E9711228CB99BeginSession.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.773 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE69240359-0001-15F1-E9711228CB99SessionApp.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.773 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE69240359-0001-15F1-E9711228CB99SessionApp.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.773 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE69240359-0001-15F1-E9711228CB99SessionOS.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.773 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE69240359-0001-15F1-E9711228CB99SessionOS.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.774 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE69240359-0001-15F1-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.774 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE69240359-0001-15F1-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.774 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE69240359-0001-15F1-E9711228CB99SessionEvent0000000000.cls_temp
2020-05-03 08:48:33.774 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99BeginSession.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.775 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99BeginSession.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.775 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99SessionApp.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.775 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99SessionApp.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.775 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99SessionOS.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.776 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99SessionOS.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.776 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.776 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.776 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99SessionEvent0000000000.cls_temp
2020-05-03 08:48:33.777 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE692E03B0-0001-174B-E9711228CB99BeginSession.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.777 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE692E03B0-0001-174B-E9711228CB99BeginSession.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.777 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE692E03B0-0001-174B-E9711228CB99SessionApp.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.778 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE692E03B0-0001-174B-E9711228CB99SessionApp.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.778 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE692E03B0-0001-174B-E9711228CB99SessionOS.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.778 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE692E03B0-0001-174B-E9711228CB99SessionOS.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.778 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE692E03B0-0001-174B-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.779 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE692E03B0-0001-174B-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.779 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE692E03B0-0001-174B-E9711228CB99SessionEvent0000000000.cls_temp
2020-05-03 08:48:33.779 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99BeginSession.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.779 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99BeginSession.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.780 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionApp.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.780 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionApp.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.780 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionOS.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.780 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionOS.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.780 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.781 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE693803E1-0001-1863-E9711228CB99BeginSession.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.781 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE693803E1-0001-1863-E9711228CB99SessionApp.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.781 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE693803E1-0001-1863-E9711228CB99SessionOS.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.782 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE693803E1-0001-1863-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.782 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE693803E1-0001-1863-E9711228CB99BeginSession.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.782 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Registered Firebase Analytics event listener for breadcrumbs: true
2020-05-03 08:48:33.782 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.782 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionEvent0000000000.cls_temp
2020-05-03 08:48:33.783 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE693803E1-0001-1863-E9711228CB99SessionApp.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.783 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE693803E1-0001-1863-E9711228CB99SessionOS.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.783 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE693803E1-0001-1863-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.784 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Moving session file: /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/5EAE693803E1-0001-1863-E9711228CB99SessionEvent0000000000.cls_temp
2020-05-03 08:48:33.786 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Trimming session file: 5EAE691400E6-0001-1476-E9711228CB99BeginSession.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.786 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Trimming session file: 5EAE691400E6-0001-1476-E9711228CB99BeginSession.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.787 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Trimming session file: 5EAE691400E6-0001-1476-E9711228CB99SessionApp.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.787 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Trimming session file: 5EAE691400E6-0001-1476-E9711228CB99SessionApp.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.787 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Trimming session file: 5EAE691400E6-0001-1476-E9711228CB99SessionOS.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.787 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Trimming session file: 5EAE691400E6-0001-1476-E9711228CB99SessionOS.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.788 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Trimming session file: 5EAE691400E6-0001-1476-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.788 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Trimming session file: 5EAE691400E6-0001-1476-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.788 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Trimming session file: 5EAE691400E6-0001-1476-E9711228CB99SessionEvent0000000000.cls_temp
2020-05-03 08:48:33.788 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Trimming session file: 5EAE69240359-0001-15F1-E9711228CB99BeginSession.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.789 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Trimming session file: 5EAE69240359-0001-15F1-E9711228CB99BeginSession.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.789 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Trimming session file: 5EAE69240359-0001-15F1-E9711228CB99SessionApp.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.789 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Trimming session file: 5EAE69240359-0001-15F1-E9711228CB99SessionApp.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.789 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Trimming session file: 5EAE69240359-0001-15F1-E9711228CB99SessionOS.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.790 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Trimming session file: 5EAE69240359-0001-15F1-E9711228CB99SessionOS.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.790 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Trimming session file: 5EAE69240359-0001-15F1-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.json
2020-05-03 08:48:33.790 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Trimming session file: 5EAE69240359-0001-15F1-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:33.790 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Trimming session file: 5EAE69240359-0001-15F1-E9711228CB99SessionEvent0000000000.cls_temp
2020-05-03 08:48:33.792 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Finalizing previously open sessions.
2020-05-03 08:48:33.799 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Closing open sessions.
2020-05-03 08:48:33.799 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Closing session: 5EAE69340228-0001-17A0-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:33.799 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Collecting session parts for ID 5EAE69340228-0001-17A0-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:33.800 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Session 5EAE69340228-0001-17A0-E9711228CB99 has fatal exception: false
2020-05-03 08:48:33.800 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Session 5EAE69340228-0001-17A0-E9711228CB99 has non-fatal exceptions: false
2020-05-03 08:48:33.800 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: No events present for session ID 5EAE69340228-0001-17A0-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:33.800 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Removing session part files for ID 5EAE69340228-0001-17A0-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:33.802 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Closing session: 5EAE692A0211-0001-1670-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:33.802 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Collecting session parts for ID 5EAE692A0211-0001-1670-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:33.803 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Session 5EAE692A0211-0001-1670-E9711228CB99 has fatal exception: false
2020-05-03 08:48:33.803 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Session 5EAE692A0211-0001-1670-E9711228CB99 has non-fatal exceptions: false
2020-05-03 08:48:33.803 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: No events present for session ID 5EAE692A0211-0001-1670-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:33.803 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Removing session part files for ID 5EAE692A0211-0001-1670-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:33.804 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Closed all previously open sessions
2020-05-03 08:48:33.808 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Initialization marker file removed: true
2020-05-03 08:48:33.809 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Starting report processing in 1.0 second(s)...
2020-05-03 08:48:34.844 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Checking for crash reports...
2020-05-03 08:48:34.856 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Found invalid session: 5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:34.857 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Found invalid session: 5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:34.858 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Found invalid session: 5EAE692E03B0-0001-174B-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:34.858 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Found invalid session: 5EAE693803E1-0001-1863-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:34.859 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Attempting to send 4 report(s)
2020-05-03 08:48:36.772 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Adding file 5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99BeginSession.json to report 5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:36.778 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Adding file 5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99BeginSession.cls to report 5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:36.783 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Adding file 5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionApp.json to report 5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:36.788 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Adding file 5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionApp.cls to report 5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:36.790 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Adding file 5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionOS.json to report 5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:36.793 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Adding file 5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionOS.cls to report 5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:36.797 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Adding file 5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.json to report 5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:36.799 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Adding file 5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.cls to report 5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:36.802 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Adding file 5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionEvent0000000000.cls_temp to report 5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:36.805 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Sending report to: https://reports.crashlytics.com/spi/v1/platforms/android/apps/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/reports
2020-05-03 08:48:37.138 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Create report request ID: null
2020-05-03 08:48:37.139 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Result was: 202
2020-05-03 08:48:37.140 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog I/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics report upload complete: 5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:37.140 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Removing invalid report file at /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/invalidClsFiles/5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99BeginSession.json
2020-05-03 08:48:37.141 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Removing invalid report file at /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/invalidClsFiles/5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99BeginSession.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:37.142 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Removing invalid report file at /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/invalidClsFiles/5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionApp.json
2020-05-03 08:48:37.144 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Removing invalid report file at /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/invalidClsFiles/5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionApp.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:37.145 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Removing invalid report file at /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/invalidClsFiles/5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionOS.json
2020-05-03 08:48:37.146 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Removing invalid report file at /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/invalidClsFiles/5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionOS.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:37.147 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Removing invalid report file at /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/invalidClsFiles/5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.json
2020-05-03 08:48:37.148 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Removing invalid report file at /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/invalidClsFiles/5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.cls
2020-05-03 08:48:37.149 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Removing invalid report file at /data/user/0/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/invalidClsFiles/5EAE69360057-0001-17F9-E9711228CB99SessionEvent0000000000.cls_temp
2020-05-03 08:48:37.177 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Adding file 5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99BeginSession.json to report 5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:37.180 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Adding file 5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99BeginSession.cls to report 5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:37.184 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Adding file 5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99SessionApp.json to report 5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:37.188 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Adding file 5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99SessionApp.cls to report 5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:37.191 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Adding file 5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99SessionOS.json to report 5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:37.194 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Adding file 5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99SessionOS.cls to report 5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:37.198 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Adding file 5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.json to report 5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:37.201 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Adding file 5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99SessionDevice.cls to report 5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:37.205 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Adding file 5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99SessionEvent0000000000.cls_temp to report 5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99
2020-05-03 08:48:37.208 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Sending report to: https://reports.crashlytics.com/spi/v1/platforms/android/apps/it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog/reports
2020-05-03 08:48:37.438 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Create report request ID: null
2020-05-03 08:48:37.439 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog D/CrashlyticsCore: Result was: 202
2020-05-03 08:48:37.439 it.unitn.disi.witmee.sensorlog I/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics report upload complete: 5EAE692C004D-0001-16D1-E9711228CB99
...
```

The fact that some reports are delivered and visible and some are only sent but not visualized is strange, and lets me think that it may be not a problem on my side. Any clue on how to address this problem?

Comment: Looking at the crash report, it seems like it's not recognizing your session. That might have to do with it, How are you crashing your app?

Comment: In many different ways, I'm very good at crashing my app :) Jokes apart, in this specific case I was forcing it by calling Crashlytics.getInstance().crash().

Comment: Hmm, are you using the new (beta) SDK, or the original legacy one?

Answer (score 1):

I may have found the issue. In my application I am using Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() to detect errors and react:

```
@Override
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

    Crashlytics.logException(e);

    Utils.closeApplicationAndRestart(context, 5000, MainActivity.class);
}
```

To make this work with Crashlytics in the past I had to add Crashlytics.logException(e). Apparently that is not working anymore now. By removing the setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(), the problem is solved. This is not really the intended solution, but I can now see the crashes in the console.